# converting this table to minimalist div

Tags: html

I've seen numerous examples on the net for converting tables to divs and none helped so far. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish...

So far, I have the following code. I excluded the CSS stylesheet in this example.

```
<table class="sh1">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=2>
      <a class="sh2" href="/"><span></span>homepage link</a>
    </th>
    <th class="sh3">
      <a href="#stc">[Skip to Content]</a>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sh5">a description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, what happens is that the span tags eventually load a logo and the "homepage link" words appear underneath it in white. the "Skip to content" text appears on the top-right and the "a description" text appears in the middle centered, which is exactly what I want.

The problem is I need to crunch this code down further so the website loads faster. I thought that using divs is nice but I feel I have a problem that can be solved ridiculously easy but the answer just slipped me.

Here's the code I attempted that failed:

```
<div class="ptop">
  <a href="/"><div></div>homepage link</a>
  <p>a description</p>
</div>
```

I have a problem getting the words "a description" in the dead center and directly to the right of the logo (which is now in the inner set of DIVs), yet I can do it perfectly fine with a table.

So basically, what I'm asking is, how can I get an image on the left hand side with a link under it, and text directly to the right of it without going to the next line, and have all this as a header?

I want to be able to make a solution that can work with as many browsers as possible. Even a nice solution that works with IE6 would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Its unusual that you wouldn't include your CSS, since that's how most of this is probably going to get done.

Here's a fiddle, with one possible way: http://jsfiddle.net/g8dg5o2e/

If you set the logo and the div next to it to both have `display:inline-block`, they'll appear in a row. Then if you set `vertical-align:top`, you're able to use the `line-height` on the description text to make it vertically center directly next to the image.

Its important that the line-height be the same as the height of the image, and of course this doesn't take into account any other CSS you may not have provided here.